# How can I create a new feature based on labels of an existing feature?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe `df` with a feature called `Subject_Car_Make` with 74 different labels.
The labels represent the car brand.

I want to create a new column that represents the region where the car brand is from: 
 i.e. 'Asian', 'European', 'American', and 'Other'.

I've tried the following, which did not work:

```
## create a list of our conditions
conditions = [
    (df.isin({'Subject_Car_Make': ['TOYOTA', 'Honda', 'Lexus', 'Hyundai', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Mitsubishi', 'Acura', 'Mazda', 'Infiniti', 'Isuzu', 'Suzuki', 'GAC', 'Subaru', 'FOTON', 'Geely', 'Ashok Leyland', 'CHANGAN', 'Yamaha', 'Howo', 'Tata', 'Rexton', 'Raston', 'Bajaj', 'Jincheng', 'BRILLIANCE', 'ZOYTE']})),
    (df.isin({'Subject_Car_Make': ['Mercedes', 'Volkswagen', 'Iveco', 'Range Rover', 'BMW', 'Land Rover', 'Land Rover.', 'Man', 'Peugeot', 'Volvo', 'Audi', 'DAF', 'Skoda', 'Porsche', 'Scania', 'Opel', 'Renault', 'Jaguar', 'MINI COOPER', 'Astra', 'Seat', 'Fiat']})),
    (df.isin({'Subject_Car_Make': ['Mack', 'Pontiac', 'Chevrolet', 'Jeep', 'Dodge', 'GMC', 'LIBERTY', 'Wrangler Jeep', 'Grand Cherokee', 'Chrysler', 'Hummer', 'Rolls Royce', 'COMMANDER', 'MG', 'Cadillac', 'Lincoln', 'Buick']})),
    (df.isin({'Subject_Car_Make': ['.', 'As Attached', 'Innson', 'Black', 'ABG', 'Ashok Leyland', 'KA', 'Motorcycle']}))
    ]

## create a list of the values we want to assign for each condition
values = ['Asian Brand', 'European Brand', 'American Brand', 'Other']

## create a new column and use np.select to assign values to it using our lists as arguments
df['Car_Brand'] = np.select(conditions, values)

## display updated DataFrame
df[['Subject_Car_Make', 'Car_Brand']].head()
```

With each dictionary, I'm trying to represent the condition or possible values in the existing column `Subject_Car_Make` and with the values, I'm trying to fill in the corresponding values for the new feature `Car_Brand`.

It seems like I'm making this unnecessarily complicated.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I think you're going about it in the right way but you should be doing `df["Subject_Car_Make"].isin(...)`. The reason it is not working (I think) is you're using `DataFrame.isin`, which is returning a dataframe and `np.select` requires a boolean array. Can you create a [mcve] that shows it not working? Also got a typo in `Rolls Royce` :)

Comment: The problem is that with your current `isin` method you get a **DataFrame**, you instead want a **Series** of Boolean values where you have a single Boolean for the entire row, so you need the Series.isin: e.g.,`df['Subject_Car_Make'].isin(['Mercedes', ...])`

Comment: Worked perfectly with such a small change. Thanks a lot! 

@Alex, the typo is in the original data :D  ... there are a couple other ones, too. 
But thanks for mentioning that!